# PHP get timestamp from separate date and time

Tags: php, date, timestamp

I have two inputs, one for the date in yyyy/mm/dd format and another for time in 12:15 AM. Now I need to save into the the databse a timestamp. I get both inputs lets say:

```
$my_date = '2013/12/22';
$my_time = '12:50 PM';
```

How do I get a timestamp to save into db?

Thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Give this a try...

```
$my_date = '2013/12/22';
$my_time = '12:50 PM';

$full_date = $my_date . ' ' . $my_time;

$timestamp = strtotime($full_date);
```

Answer (score 1):

Use [`DateTime:createFromFormat()`](http://www.php.net/manual/en/datetime.createfromformat.php)

```
<?php

$my_date = '2013/12/22';
$my_time = '12:50 PM';

$d = sprintf('%s %s', $my_date, $my_time);

$dt = DateTime::createFromFormat('Y/m/d h:i A',  $d);
$ts = $dt->getTimestamp();

var_dump($ts);
```

Yields:

```
int 1387716600
```

Hope this helps :)

**Edit**

- [PHP's date format reference](http://php.net/manual/en/function.date.php)

Comment: I've upvoted this answer 'cause I believe this is the best and most updated answer so far here, but it seems that somebody after me have downvoted that as well. Just out of curiosity wondering what was the reason for that? Is there anything wrong with this answer?

Comment: Thank you @Mahdi. I'd also appreciate a comment on the downvote. Someone downvoted the accepted answer as well. Clearly these answers are not incorrect nor inaccurate. It's pretty mean spirited in my view to downvote without giving some sort of reason/feedback.

Comment: Regarding the answer itself, I work with dates and times a lot and I personally prefer to use the `DateTime` family of classes (`DateTimeZone`, `DateInterval`, `DatePeriod` etc.) because it provides some good functionality and flexibility. That said, there's nothing wrong with `strtotime` functions either - it's simply a matter of utility and desired functionality. I specifically used `createFromFormat` in this case because of the unusual format (Y/m/d, is like ISO8601 except it uses slashes) and explicitly defining the input format would minimise possible errors.

Comment: Yeah, I'm not sure what's going on with the down voting around here...  both of the correct answers (this and mine) were down voted, which doesn't make any sense to me at all.

Answer (score 0):

You could use strtotime() to convert it into an UNIX timestamp.

E.g.:

```
$my_date = strtotime('2013/12/22');
$my_time = strtotime('12:50 PM');
```

Full date + time timestamp

```
$timestamp = strtotime('2013/12/22 12:50 PM');
```

More info: http://php.net/manual/en/function.strtotime.php

Comment: but how do I get the whole date in one timestamp?

Comment: @AlejandroCasas like this `strtotime('2013/12/22 12:50 PM');`

Comment: @mahdi why do you accept another answer that is the same as mine and posted minutes later and accept that?

Comment: Your original answer was wrong.  Your edited answer is closer but still does not show the OP how to put his two variables together in to one string and then convert.  The accepted answer provides the exact code to address the OP's problem.

Comment: @edwardmp I guess you're a little bit confused. This is not my question, or maybe you meant AlejandroCasas instead of me?

Comment: @mahid what do you mean not your question? It's the exact same as the question you accepted, but I gave my example directly instead of using a $var

Comment: @edwardmp Well, I'm just simply saying that this is not my question at all, I was just commenting here. `AlejandroCasas` were asking this question and you're answering him also. I can't accept any answers here. :)

Comment: I meant @AlejandroCasas indeed, sorry

Comment: @edwardmp Yeah, I thought the same as well. :)

Comment: @Charlie74 Are you kidding me, do I have to assume the OP does not know how to input a var? LOL

Comment: @edwardmp umm...  sadly it seems that may have been the case.   At least that's the difference between the two answers.